# Difference between Apache Storm releases?

Tags: apache-storm

Apache Storm (http://storm.apache.org/downloads.html) has:

- Current 1.0.x Release: apache-storm-1.0.2.tar.gz
- Current 0.10.x Release: apache-storm-0.10.1.tar.gz
- Current 0.9.x Release: apache-storm-0.9.7.tar.gz

What are the differences between all these releases? Can't find any information about this. Which one to use? Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just starting, I would recommend going with the 1.0.x release. It is going to be maintained the longest of 1.0, 0.10, and 0.9. I think support for 0.9 has already dropped, actually.

2.0 has not been released yet and may not be for some time. 1.0 is still being actively developed.